# ¿management studio sqlServer NO habilita script alter function partition?

Tags: sql-server

Realice una partición en una tabla (dos particiones) por fecha.

La función original es:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [EsquemaParticion2] AS PARTITION [FuncionParticion] 
TO ([Historico1], [PRIMARY])
```

Necesito modificar esta partición agregando una nueva partición, ya modifique el esquema.

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME EsquemaParticion
NEXT USED Historico2;
```

Ahora quiero modificar la función

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION FuncionParticion() SPLIT RANGE (N'2016-01- 
01T00:00:00')
```

Me sale este error:

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 3

Cannot alter the partition function 'FuncionParticion', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

La función ya verifique y si existe. Estoy trabajando con el usuario sa
Desde Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio me deshabilita la opción del `ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si la función existe, entonces el problema es que no tienes el permiso para hacerle `ALTER`

Comment: ¿Que permiso adicional debería de tener si estoy trabajando con el usuario users sa (sysadmin)?

Comment: Ah, no leí esa parte de la pregunta, ese usuario no debería tener problemas. Ahora, tampoco funciona con código?, viendo tu pregunta, el nombre de la función que usas en el ALTER es diferente al nombre que te lanza el error. Seguro que lo estás haciendo correctamente?

Comment: Se me paso borrar el nombre de la tabla, es dato confidencial, perdón.

Comment: El problema creo q esta en ¿por que Microsoft SQL Management Studio me deshabilita la opción de generar el script ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION? supongo que por lo mismo desde el código me genera ese error, lo ejecute desde el administrator de window y me larga el mismo error.